# Is jQuery´s extend creating a reference between the objects?

Tags: jquery, object, reference, extend

I am extending shat with shot. After extending, why does modifying shot alter shat?

```
var shat = [{bang:true}, {bumm: false}, {bong: false}]
var shot = [{bang:false}, {bumm: false}, {bong: false}]

$.extend(shat, shot)

shot[0].bang = true

console.log("shat", shat) 
// prints
Object
bang: true // why is this true?
Object
bumm: false
Object
bong: false
```

I am assuming a reference is created or the extending is for some reason happening after the shot[0].bang = true. The problem is, I want to modify shot after the extending, but of course dont want to have it any effect on shat. Any ideas why this is happening and what I could do to avoid that?

see jSfiddle testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/yEnph/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `$.extend` merely shallow-copies properties*. It's not very exciting.

In this case, the extended properties are "0", "1", "2", etc, and thus ***`shat[0] === shot[0]` is true after extending*** which is *only* the case if both evaluate to *the same* object. Since they are the same object then ... well, mutating it one place mutates it *everywhere*.

To keep them separate consider a "deep copy" (see the different ways to invoked [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)). Another approach, that I mention because it can also be used in other contexts, is to serialize the object and then de-serialize it -- e.g. with JSON.

```
var shat = [{bang:true}, {bumm: false}, {bong: false}]
var shot = [{bang:false}, {bumm: false}, {bong: false}]
$.extend(true, shat, shot) // use "deep copy"
shat[0] === shot[0]        // false; different objects now so...
shot[0].bang = "boom"      // ...this will not affect the object named by shat[0]
shot[0].bang               // "boom"
shat[0].bang               // false
```

Happy coding.

---

*That is, for every property, `p`, in the source object(s), it merely does `target[p] = source[p]`. Remember that, in JavaScript, Arrays are just a special subtype of object with a magical `length`: the value at index n is named by the property "n".

Comment: But, shat[1] === shot[1] is true, too. How to explain that?

Comment: @GraceShao It will be true for all `shat[x] === shot[x]`, where `x` was an extended property: I messed up, as I should have said "1" and "2" are also copied :) You are *very correct* in your answer: it doesn't treat arrays special. However, `shat` and `shot` are still two different objects: the properties from `shat` have just been augmented (overridden) with those from `shot`.

Comment: it makes sense, kind of :-), now I am tyring to understand why there isn´t any problem when doing something like here http://jsfiddle.net/qnBmn/

Comment: @Marcel Because the values of the properties copied are immutable -- so even if they were to be `===`, there is no way to mutate them :) Remember that `shot` and `shat` name two separate *objects* so mutating one -- *assigning a different value to a property* -- does not affect the other. In the original post a *shared object* was mutated (namely: `{bang: false}`).

Comment: Consider: `var a = {v: "foo"}; var x = {}; var y = {a: a}; x.a = y.a; y.a.v = "bar";` Then these are true: `a === x.a`, `a === y.a`, and, `a.v === "bar"`. (The object named by `a` was mutated: the above creates only *one* object with the property "v".)

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery document http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/, it looks like $.extend only does Object augments, but not Array. In the example, your `shat` variable has never been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that that works at all, wasn't aware that `extend` worked on arrays.

The reason for this though is that the two arrays both contain a reference to the same object.  It's the same reason that this will alert "new":

http://jsfiddle.net/yEnph/4/

```
var a = { test: "one"};
var b = a;

a.test="new";

alert(b.test);
```

Both variables have a reference to the same object so editing the object updates the object, which they both reference.

Comment: ok I get this, but nowhere I am doing something like a = b or shat = shot

Comment: Internally `extend` is doing something like `shat[0]=shot[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Extend just overwrites the properties if the keys are taken:

```
var a = {
   hello: "kitty"
},

b = {
   hello: "world"
}

$.extend( a, b );

console.log( a );
//Object
//hello: "world"
```

Because arrays are just objects with numeric property names, you will replace them with same principle except `"hello"` is `"0"`, and so on.

Because you have objects instead of primitives, `shat` gets `shot`'s objects, they are rewritten so the original `shat` objects are lost. So modifying `shot`'s objects will modify `shat`'s objects because they are the same objects.